# Example of a set whose interior is countably infinite.

Tags: real-analysis

Our teacher asked to give an example of set whose interior is countably infinite. I can't construct it.

Comment: a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: An interior is always an open set. In $\Bbb R^n$ all the nonempty open sets are uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the metric space $\mathbb R$ every open set is either empty or uncountable. This is because open sets are unions of open intervals, and the non-empty open intervals are all uncountable. So no subset of $\mathbb R$ is countably infinite.

However there are some other metric spaces in which countably infinite open sets exist. It suffices to take a metric space that is itself countably infinfite. An example of such a metric space is $\mathbb Z$ with the euclidean norm. Notice that in this metric space $\mathbb Z$ itself is an open set that is countably infinite (so its interior is itself and is countably infinite).

Comment: Ok but how do I show that in Z , Z is open?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: much clearer!

Comment: the complete set is always an open subset of itself, for every metric space. It is clearly the union of all of the open balls.

Comment: Thank you !! You explained it beautifully

Comment: No problem ${}{}{}$

Answer (score -1):

In $R$ under the usual metric it can't be since if it is an interior then it is open and if it is open then it should contain a nbd of each of it's points and nbds in$ R $are uncountable.and a countable set cant contain an uncountable subset